# Is it possible to sort dictionary by list values if lists in such dictionary are keys? (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sorting

I have the following dictionary in my python program:

```
{
    "[1367.720947265625, 1444.2767333984375, 1521.06689453125, 1485.356689453125]": "subtotal",
    "[1195.419921875, 1294.1451416015625, 1261.998779296875, 1347.4837646484375]": "quantity",
    "[1011.36669921875, 1035.9566650390625, 1113.5701904296875, 1078.0264892578125]": "unitPrice",
    "[1188.89501953125, 1164.5587158203125, 1256.919921875, 1212.3499755859375]": "quantity",
    "[1402.3472900390625, 1298.7572021484375, 1522.4576416015625, 1340.8663330078125]": "lineTotal",
    "[1264.884765625, 147.79635620117188, 1519.5789794921875, 186.50259399414062]": "billFrom",
    "[1009.4990234375, 1168.522216796875, 1110.963623046875, 1208.9124755859375]": "unitPrice",
    "[1385.47412109375, 1168.2421875, 1517.8038330078125, 1210.4647216796875]": "lineTotal",
    "[1401.8753662109375, 1035.643310546875, 1516.5439453125, 1079.564208984375]": "lineTotal",
    "[999.4454956054688, 1300.4671630859375, 1110.5958251953125, 1340.71826171875]": "unitPrice",
    "[1183.2669677734375, 1034.6751708984375, 1254.4659423828125, 1082.58056640625]": "quantity",
    "[140.36473083496094, 596.3900756835938, 411.9376525878906, 631.8897094726562]": "shippingStreet",
    "[141.6397705078125, 554.58740234375, 300.67864990234375, 591.7457885742188]": "billTo",
    "[889.7088012695312, 683.4542846679688, 1042.3240966796875, 717.8583374023438]": "dueDate",
    "[1022.4515380859375, 1214.6746826171875, 1113.29443359375, 1254.3046875]": "unitPrice",
    "[1388.4552001953125, 1167.39404296875, 1518.3984375, 1213.6607666015625]": "unitPrice",
    "[883.4694213867188, 553.4235229492188, 1046.925048828125, 588.238037109375]": "invoiceDate",
    "[1025.562744140625, 1083.2025146484375, 1112.4288330078125, 1121.55419921875]": "unitPrice",
    "[144.29791259765625, 1183.788330078125, 476.667236328125, 1266.81298828125]": "itemDescription",
    "[1287.64208984375, 197.3350067138672, 1523.859375, 234.3388214111328]": "billingStreet",
    "[140.41636657714844, 724.60986328125, 337.17510986328125, 754.7083129882812]": "shippingStreet",
    "[129.31320190429688, 766.5986938476562, 369.9432067871094, 799.400146484375]": "shippingPhone",
    "[1387.3717041015625, 1680.0711669921875, 1518.840576171875, 1719.1527099609375]": "total",
    "[147.7745361328125, 1313.5689697265625, 689.4801025390625, 1394.5797119140625]": "itemDescription",
    "[149.51734924316406, 1054.5794677734375, 424.2734069824219, 1136.7952880859375]": "itemDescription",
    "[1381.0460205078125, 1496.8577880859375, 1519.4583740234375, 1534.3375244140625]": "tax"
}
```

I want to sort it so that it looked like

```
{
    "[1264.884765625, 147.79635620117188, 1519.5789794921875, 186.50259399414062]": "billFrom",
    "[141.6397705078125, 554.58740234375, 300.67864990234375, 591.7457885742188]": "billTo",
    ...
    "[other list]": "itemDescription",
    "[another list]": "quantity",
    "[another list]": "unitPrice",
    "[another list]": "lineTotal],
    ...
    "[another list]": "subtotal",
    "[another list]": "tax",
    "[another list]": "total"
}
```

The values are labels and keys are lists of coordinates of corresponding bounding boxes, they encode detected text on the image.

I tried to sort just by keys but I didn't get expected result.

```
def sort_invoice_dict_by_keys(self, invoice_dict: dict) -> dict:
        sorted_invoice_dict = dict(sorted(invoice_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[0]))
        print(json.dumps(sorted_invoice_dict, indent=4))
        return sorted_invoice_dict
```

the output was:

```
{
    "[1009.4990234375, 1168.522216796875, 1110.963623046875, 1208.9124755859375]": "unitPrice",
    "[1011.36669921875, 1035.9566650390625, 1113.5701904296875, 1078.0264892578125]": "unitPrice",
    "[1022.4515380859375, 1214.6746826171875, 1113.29443359375, 1254.3046875]": "unitPrice",
    "[1025.562744140625, 1083.2025146484375, 1112.4288330078125, 1121.55419921875]": "unitPrice",
    "[1183.2669677734375, 1034.6751708984375, 1254.4659423828125, 1082.58056640625]": "quantity",
    "[1188.89501953125, 1164.5587158203125, 1256.919921875, 1212.3499755859375]": "quantity",
    "[1195.419921875, 1294.1451416015625, 1261.998779296875, 1347.4837646484375]": "quantity",
    "[1264.884765625, 147.79635620117188, 1519.5789794921875, 186.50259399414062]": "billFrom",
    "[1287.64208984375, 197.3350067138672, 1523.859375, 234.3388214111328]": "billingStreet",
    "[129.31320190429688, 766.5986938476562, 369.9432067871094, 799.400146484375]": "shippingPhone",
    "[1367.720947265625, 1444.2767333984375, 1521.06689453125, 1485.356689453125]": "subtotal",
    "[1381.0460205078125, 1496.8577880859375, 1519.4583740234375, 1534.3375244140625]": "tax",
    "[1385.47412109375, 1168.2421875, 1517.8038330078125, 1210.4647216796875]": "lineTotal",
    "[1387.3717041015625, 1680.0711669921875, 1518.840576171875, 1719.1527099609375]": "total",
    "[1388.4552001953125, 1167.39404296875, 1518.3984375, 1213.6607666015625]": "unitPrice",
    "[140.36473083496094, 596.3900756835938, 411.9376525878906, 631.8897094726562]": "shippingStreet",
    "[140.41636657714844, 724.60986328125, 337.17510986328125, 754.7083129882812]": "shippingStreet",
    "[1401.8753662109375, 1035.643310546875, 1516.5439453125, 1079.564208984375]": "lineTotal",
    "[1402.3472900390625, 1298.7572021484375, 1522.4576416015625, 1340.8663330078125]": "lineTotal",
    "[141.6397705078125, 554.58740234375, 300.67864990234375, 591.7457885742188]": "billTo",
    "[144.29791259765625, 1183.788330078125, 476.667236328125, 1266.81298828125]": "itemDescription",
    "[147.7745361328125, 1313.5689697265625, 689.4801025390625, 1394.5797119140625]": "itemDescription",
    "[149.51734924316406, 1054.5794677734375, 424.2734069824219, 1136.7952880859375]": "itemDescription",
    "[883.4694213867188, 553.4235229492188, 1046.925048828125, 588.238037109375]": "invoiceDate",
    "[889.7088012695312, 683.4542846679688, 1042.3240966796875, 717.8583374023438]": "dueDate",
    "[999.4454956054688, 1300.4671630859375, 1110.5958251953125, 1340.71826171875]": "unitPrice"
}
```

I also tried to sort it by values setting  `item: item[1]` but it just sorted in alphabetical order which is not what i want. Any ideas how to solve this? Is that possible at all?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for at all.  And your keys aren't lists, they're strings that *look* like lists.

Comment: P.S. your example output is impossible, because it contains multiple entries for the same key.  Dictionaries don't work like that.

Comment: @MarkRansom yeah, sorry for confusion... I wrapped them into strings because we can't have list as a key. What I want is to sort keys by those 4 values so that labels would be sorted as well.

Comment: @MarkRansom OK, if it's not possible then... I probably should find some another way. Thank you :)

Comment: You can have tuples as keys instead of lists. But I strongly advise you not to use floats as (part of the) key.

Comment: @Stef Oh realy?? I completele forgot about that! :) Speaking about floats as keys, I get it but I basically have no choice in my case. So can I do smth like
`dict(sorted(invoice_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]...))`??

Comment: @unix101 I think dictionary is not the best tool for your usecase.

Comment: In general, whenever you have `dict(sorted(some_dict.items()))` in your code, that's a pretty huge hint that you shouldn't be using a dict in the first place.

Comment: @Stef well, you see, the case is, I have to parse invoices to JSON. I trained my model and it detected some fileds and returned their bboxes with labels. I now need to extract the actual values using those boxes and map them to corresponding labels to get appropriate structure. So I guess I have no choice haha :)

Comment: @Stef but If you have better idea i'd be thankful if you shared it :)

Comment: @unix101 I insist, I'm sure dictionaries are not the right tool for this. However, it's very hard for me to understand exactly what you're doing, and right know all I know about your problem is that you have some data in a dict, so I have no idea what you want to do with this and what structure would be best. But from what you've shown, a dict certainly sounds very inappropriate. Perhaps even a simple list of pairs would be better. But I can't say for sure because I don't understand what you're doing.

Comment: `{bboxes: [ { box: [1,2,3,4], label: "frog" },... ], ...}`

Comment: Can you explain your required output? Why is the key [beginning] "[1264.884765625" at the start of the list? I get that 'billFrom' is the lowest value in terms of lexicographical ordering but your required output ends with 'total' so I'm really not sure what you're sorting on

Comment: You can parse and dump json with the json library.  List keys aren't valid json either: the list should be a value.

Comment: @Stef ok, I'll explain more in depth. So I'm implementing a Salesforce app to parse invoices (read their data and store it in JSON format) to generate Salesforce objects based on that JSON. For that, I trained YOLO neural network. It detects values of different types (e.g. billFrom, billTo etc) and returns their bboxes and labels. I need to generate JSON out of that data, to send it to Salesforce app which will process it smh else. As I have only bboxes not actual text, I want to map firstly that bboxes to appropriate labels, then extract actual data using that bboxes

Comment: @Stef basically using those bboxes to crop incoming invoice image by them (Pillow is used) and read the text that got into bbox (pytesseract is used)

Comment: @DarkKnight If you take a look at some invoices - most of them start with billFrom
(some with invoiceNumber or companyName probably) and end with Total or amountDue etc. Lists are values because fields like UnitPrice or Description are not always unique, there can be several of them. And I want to group them in a list of objects like `"items":[{"desc": "value1", "qty": "value2"...}, ... {another similar object from another line}...]`.

Comment: @DarkKnight in general I want my output to be like:
`'SUBTOTAL': '$999.00', 'INVOICE DATE': '2022-12-27', 'AMOUNT DUE': '$1,128.87', 'TAX (13.0%)': '$129.87', 'Country': '', 'City': None, 'Postal code': '', 'Street': '', 'State': None, 'Phone number': '', 'Email': None, 'Company name': '', 'items': [{'Item': 'Iphone 12', 'Description': 'Iphone 12 BLACK 12 GB', 'Quantity': '1.0', 'Unit Cost': '$999.00'}, {'Item': 'SUBTOTAL', 'Description': '$999.00'}]}`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I managed to resolve the issue, here is how:

```
def sort_invoice_dict_by_keys(self, invoice_dict: dict) -> dict:
        # sorted_invoice_dict = dict(sorted(invoice_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[0]))
        # print(f"sorted invoice === {json.dumps(sorted_invoice_dict, indent=4)}")\

        sorted_invoice_dict = {} # copy original dict
        for k, v in invoice_dict.items():
            sorted_invoice_dict[tuple(ast.literal_eval(k))] = v

        # sort elements by keys 
        sorted_invoice_dict = dict(sorted(sorted_invoice_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (x[0][0], x[0][2]))) # sort by x
        sorted_invoice_dict = dict(sorted(sorted_invoice_dict.items(), key=lambda y: (y[0][1], y[0][3]))) # sort by y
        
        # FOR DEBUG ONLY - display encoded sorted data in JSON FORMAT
        sorted_invoice_dict_jsonified = {}
        for k, v in sorted_invoice_dict.items():
            sorted_invoice_dict_jsonified[str(k)] = v
        print(f"sorted encoded invoice === {json.dumps(sorted_invoice_dict_jsonified, indent=4)}")

        return sorted_invoice_dict
```

And the output:

```
sorted encoded invoice === {
    "(1264.884765625, 147.79635620117188, 1519.5789794921875, 186.50259399414062)": "billFrom",
    "(1287.64208984375, 197.3350067138672, 1523.859375, 234.3388214111328)": "billingStreet",
    "(883.4694213867188, 553.4235229492188, 1046.925048828125, 588.238037109375)": "invoiceDate",
    "(141.6397705078125, 554.58740234375, 300.67864990234375, 591.7457885742188)": "billTo",
    "(140.36473083496094, 596.3900756835938, 411.9376525878906, 631.8897094726562)": "shippingStreet",
    "(889.7088012695312, 683.4542846679688, 1042.3240966796875, 717.8583374023438)": "dueDate",
    "(140.41636657714844, 724.60986328125, 337.17510986328125, 754.7083129882812)": "shippingStreet",
    "(129.31320190429688, 766.5986938476562, 369.9432067871094, 799.400146484375)": "shippingPhone",
    "(1183.2669677734375, 1034.6751708984375, 1254.4659423828125, 1082.58056640625)": "quantity",
    "(1401.8753662109375, 1035.643310546875, 1516.5439453125, 1079.564208984375)": "lineTotal",
    "(1011.36669921875, 1035.9566650390625, 1113.5701904296875, 1078.0264892578125)": "unitPrice",
    "(149.51734924316406, 1054.5794677734375, 424.2734069824219, 1136.7952880859375)": "itemDescription",
    "(1025.562744140625, 1083.2025146484375, 1112.4288330078125, 1121.55419921875)": "unitPrice",
    "(1188.89501953125, 1164.5587158203125, 1256.919921875, 1212.3499755859375)": "quantity",
    "(1388.4552001953125, 1167.39404296875, 1518.3984375, 1213.6607666015625)": "unitPrice",
    "(1385.47412109375, 1168.2421875, 1517.8038330078125, 1210.4647216796875)": "lineTotal",
    "(1009.4990234375, 1168.522216796875, 1110.963623046875, 1208.9124755859375)": "unitPrice",
    "(144.29791259765625, 1183.788330078125, 476.667236328125, 1266.81298828125)": "itemDescription",
    "(1022.4515380859375, 1214.6746826171875, 1113.29443359375, 1254.3046875)": "unitPrice",
    "(1195.419921875, 1294.1451416015625, 1261.998779296875, 1347.4837646484375)": "quantity",
    "(1402.3472900390625, 1298.7572021484375, 1522.4576416015625, 1340.8663330078125)": "lineTotal",
    "(999.4454956054688, 1300.4671630859375, 1110.5958251953125, 1340.71826171875)": "unitPrice",
    "(147.7745361328125, 1313.5689697265625, 689.4801025390625, 1394.5797119140625)": "itemDescription",
    "(1367.720947265625, 1444.2767333984375, 1521.06689453125, 1485.356689453125)": "subtotal",
    "(1381.0460205078125, 1496.8577880859375, 1519.4583740234375, 1534.3375244140625)": "tax",
    "(1387.3717041015625, 1680.0711669921875, 1518.840576171875, 1719.1527099609375)": "total"
}
```